# Fix bulging back wall in GE Monogram zdwr240 wine reserve

Tags: repair, appliances

In my pantry I have a under the counter wine cellar. Suddenly the door wouldn't close anymore. A little investigation showed that the back wall was bulging significantly. I am tempted to just try use some force and end it outward, but am afraid to completely break the otherwise functioning appliance.

[image: top left corner of backwall]

What could have caused this and is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't close the door, it does not function so well either. Unplug the cooler, let it warm up completely to room temperature, maybe even add a little heat, but not too hot, warm to the touch, from a hair dryer, and give it a shove back in with the part of your hand that is near the wrist. You may need to pull it out of the space, lean it back a bit, but not too much, the refrigerant doesn't like it. and push it back in.

There was something that did that, it must have somehow been pushed severely from the back side, at least so I guess. Check the back for any sign of abuse that may keep it from going back in.

Before you try that, the crease is really predominate at the corner. After warming it up, put JUST your thumb over the middle of the sharpest part of the crease, and push steady and hard if you need to, the rest should follow. If you have a well rounded LARGE handle you may be able to use that instead. Since the handle has no feeling you will not be able to govern how the progress is going. It may be more prone to cracking the PVC shell that is deformed. If it does, humidity may enter the casing, that may or may not be ok.

Comment: Thanks for you response! Two quick clarifications: The warped wall is actually metal. I also checked the back of the unit, because the first thing I expected was that something dented it from behind. However, the back is perfectly fine.
Do you still think I should warm it up a little and push?

Comment: Quite surprised it is metal. The finish over the metal should be cracking if it is enamel or some type of painted finish. Since it is metal then a piece of wood about 2"x2" and about 2' ft long so it will reach into the back and place it over the middle of the crease and drive it in with a hammer. You will not need to warm it up, that was only for a plastic liner.

Comment: It may mar the finish doing it this way, it can be touched up with a touch up paint for appliances. It will at least get it so it will work properly. Before you do any of this, please, please make sure it is metal, the plastic WILL get damaged using this process. This is only good for metal. Driving in the crease, the rest of the metal will surely follow. You may still have a wrinkle in the back, but the back will be back in place enough to get you door working again